# Lebesgue sets of functions

Tags: derivatives, lebesgue-integral

Assume that $f \in L^1_{loc}(R^n)$ and let $x\in R^n$ and let $x\in R^n$. Assume that for every sequence $E_1, E_2 , E_3\ldots$ converging regularly to x there exists

$\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{1}{\lambda(E_k)} \int_{E_k} f(y) dy $.

Prove that x belongs to the Lebesgue set of f .

I guess that I will have to begin by showing that I can assume that f is real valued, and then show that the above limit obtained by interlacing two sequences is independent of the particular sequence in $E_k$ and then probably proceed !!

Atleast this is the brief outline that I discussed with a math PHD student , but I cannot see how to proceed formally in this way.

Definition of lebegue set :

Suppose $ f \in L^1_{loc} and ,   X \in R^n$ . Then x is a point in the lebesgue set of f if there exists a number A such that

$lim_{r=0} 1/(\lambda(B(x,r)) * \int_{B(x,r)} |f(y)-A|dy = 0 $

Comment: I don't think the statement ist true in its current form. Take $f (x)=1$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f (0)=0$ and then $x=0$.

Comment: @PhoemueX I think that that shouldn't be the problem as the question was mentioned like in the book ! ( I am using Lebesgue Integration  on Euclidean Space by Frank Jones )

Comment: Then, what is your definition of the Lebesgue set of a function?

Comment: @PhoemueX I hope this makes more sense now .